# Android - Get value from Service and using it in Widget

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, widget

I am developing a simple `C#` Android app, which runs in Background and does a specific calculation, I have a also a widget with a TexTview in which I want to display the Calculation result.

**Service.cs**

```
Intent intent = new Intent("TEST");
intent.PutExtra("alltotale", total.ToString());
this.SendBroadcast(intent);
```

Then in `BroadcastReceiver` class, I have:

**Receiver.cs**

```
 public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        string nh = intent.GetStringExtra("alltotale");
        Toast.MakeText(context, nh, ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
```

Now I want to re-use this value and display it in the widget TextView but it is not working, I am getting nothing in my `Widget`.

**AppWidget.cs**

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Label = "Widget1")]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" })]
[MetaData("android.appwidget.provider", Resource = "@xml/appwidgetprovider")]
public class AppWidget : AppWidgetProvider
{
    Intent intent;
    public override void OnUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
    {
        var me = new ComponentName(context, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(AppWidget)).Name);
        appWidgetManager.UpdateAppWidget(me, BuildRemoteViews(context, appWidgetIds));

    }
    private RemoteViews BuildRemoteViews(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds)
    {
        var widgetView = new RemoteViews(context.PackageName, Resource.Layout.Widget);

        SetTextViewText(widgetView);
        RegisterClicks(context, appWidgetIds, widgetView);

        return widgetView;
    }
    private void SetTextViewText(RemoteViews widgetView)
    {
        string oo = intent.GetStringExtra("alltotale");
        widgetView.SetTextViewText(Resource.Id.widgetMedium, "Dabboussi");
        widgetView.SetTextViewText(Resource.Id.widgetSmall, oo);
    }
    private static string AnnouncementClick = "AnnouncementClickTag";
    private void RegisterClicks(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds, RemoteViews widgetView)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(context, typeof(AppWidget));
        intent.SetAction(AppWidgetManager.ActionAppwidgetUpdate);
        intent.PutExtra(AppWidgetManager.ExtraAppwidgetIds, appWidgetIds);

        // Register click event for the Background
        var piBackground = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
        widgetView.SetOnClickPendingIntent(Resource.Id.widgetAnnouncementIcon, GetPendingSelfIntent(context, AnnouncementClick));
    }
    private PendingIntent GetPendingSelfIntent(Context context, string action)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(context, typeof(AppWidget));
        intent.SetAction(action);
        return PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    }
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        base.OnReceive(context, intent);
        var data = intent.GetStringExtra("alltotale");

        if (data != null)
        {
            var updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.PackageName, Resource.Layout.Widget);
            SetTextViewText(updateViews);
            ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(AppWidget)).Name);
            AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.GetInstance(context);
            manager.UpdateAppWidget(thisWidget, updateViews);
        }
        if (AnnouncementClick.Equals(intent.Action))
        {
            Toast.MakeText(context, "OPEN", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            // Open another app
        }
    }
}
```

So, the value is being displayed in the `Toast` message in background but nothing in the widget `textview`. Why is that and how can I solve it ?

**Edit**

I have thought that maybe `ISharedPreferences` would do the trick, so I did the following:

**Service.cs**

```
Intent priceIntent = new Intent("com.xamarin.example.TEST");
priceIntent.PutExtra("alltotale", total.ToString());
this.SendBroadcast(priceIntent);
ISharedPreferences prSer = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
ISharedPreferencesEditor prEd = prSer.Edit();
prEd.PutInt("PriceTot", Convert.ToInt32(total));
```

then in the **AppWidget.cs** file I did the following:

```
  [BroadcastReceiver(Label = "Widget1")]
  [IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE", "com.xamarin.example.TEST" })]
[MetaData("android.appwidget.provider", Resource = "@xml/appwidgetprovider")]
public class AppWidget : AppWidgetProvider
{
    Intent intent;
    public override void OnUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
    {
        var me = new ComponentName(context, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(AppWidget)).Name);
        appWidgetManager.UpdateAppWidget(me, BuildRemoteViews(context, appWidgetIds));

    }
    private RemoteViews BuildRemoteViews(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds)
    {
        var widgetView = new RemoteViews(context.PackageName, Resource.Layout.Widget);

        //SetTextViewText(widgetView);
        RegisterClicks(context, appWidgetIds, widgetView);

        return widgetView;
    }
    private void SetTextViewText(RemoteViews widgetView)
    {
            widgetView.SetTextViewText(Resource.Id.widgetMedium, "Don Dabboussi");
            widgetView.SetTextViewText(Resource.Id.widgetSmall, "KK");
   }
    private static string AnnouncementClick = "AnnouncementClickTag";
    private void RegisterClicks(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds, RemoteViews widgetView)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(context, typeof(AppWidget));
        intent.SetAction(AppWidgetManager.ActionAppwidgetUpdate);
        intent.PutExtra(AppWidgetManager.ExtraAppwidgetIds, appWidgetIds);

        // Register click event for the Background
        var piBackground = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
        //widgetView.SetOnClickPendingIntent(Resource.Id.widgetAnnouncementIcon, GetPendingSelfIntent(context, AnnouncementClick));
    }
    private PendingIntent GetPendingSelfIntent(Context context, string action)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(context, typeof(AppWidget));
        intent.SetAction(action);
        return PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    }
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        base.OnReceive(context, intent);
        ISharedPreferences prSer = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        var data = prSer.GetInt("PriceTot", 0);
        if (data != 0)
        {
            var updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.PackageName, Resource.Layout.Widget);
            SetTextViewText(updateViews);
            ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(AppWidget)).Name);
            AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.GetInstance(context);
            manager.UpdateAppWidget(thisWidget, updateViews);
        }
        if (AnnouncementClick.Equals(intent.Action))
        {
            Toast.MakeText(context, "OPEN", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            // Open another app
        }
    }
```

But that didn't worked, there are no text in the textviews in my widget (no `dabboussi` and no `kk`). Why is that ?

Answer (score 0):

You put a string named `alltotale` and you ask for a string named `widgetTotale`, so it is normal if it is not working. You have to change `widgetTotale` by `alltotale`

Comment: Yes, it was spelling error, in my app i asked correctly for the `alltotale` and it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to get [`AppWidgetManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager) and call `UpdateAppWidget()` method to update the widget.

For example:

```
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        base.OnReceive(context, intent);

        var data = intent.GetStringExtra("alltotale");

        if(data != null)
        {
            var updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.PackageName, Resource.Layout.widget);
            SetTextViewText(updateViews, intent);
            // Push update for this widget to the home screen
            ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(MyWidget)).Name);
            AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.GetInstance(context);
            manager.UpdateAppWidget(thisWidget, updateViews);
        }
    }

    private void SetTextViewText(RemoteViews widgetView, Intent intent)
    {
        string oo = intent.GetStringExtra("alltotale");
        widgetView.SetTextViewText(Resource.Id.widgetMedium, "Dabboussi");
        widgetView.SetTextViewText(Resource.Id.widgetSmall, oo);
    }
```

And you could refer to this [official demo](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/SimpleWidget) for more information.

Comment: Didn't worked. I have edited my code: I have added the 'OnReceive' method in the `AppWidget.cs`, but also when I click the widget nothing is happening, a `Toast` message saying OPEN should be shown. What's wrong ?

Comment: @Wassim01 Did the `OnReceive()` method in  your `AppWidget.cs` fired when the service send the broadcast?

Comment: No, it did not.

Comment: @Wassim01 Have you registered your widget?

Comment: Yes, I will provide my whole code for the `AppWidget.cs`. Please give it a look.

Comment: @Wassim01 Please try `[IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE","TEST" })]`

Comment: @Wassim01 I have uploaded [a demo to github](https://github.com/Billycool1020/GetvaluefromService), please check it. When I test your code, there are null exception in `SetTextViewText()` when the first time call `OnUpdate()`, Please 
 make sure the data is not null.

Comment: Sorry to be late. Well, I am still getting a null exception when trying to get the string from intent in `SetTextViewText` although I have used your code in the demo on `github`, and I am sure that the value is not null since it is being displayed in a `toast` message in the same time. I am thinking maybe I should use `Bundle` to pass the value to the widget instead of `intent`

Comment: @Wassim01 Could you provide a demo project so that I can help you to solve it?